# Use Bearer token with Openapi generator generated dart-dio API client

Tags: flutter, dart, bearer-token, openapi-generator, dio

I have generated dart-dio API client with Openapi generator. I use it to login and obtain Bearer token. Then I call this:

```
openapi.setBearerAuth('Authorization', 'Bearer: $token');
```

I am not sure what values exactly should I pass here - that might be the problem. When I use API call for secured endpoint, authorization header is not sent which leads to 401 error.

```
openapi
.getSomethingApi
          .apiSomethingGet();
```

But it works when I specify the headers:

```
openapi
.getSomethingApi
          .apiSomethingGet(headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer: $token'});
```

Did I misunderstand using authorization in Openapi generator generated dart-dio code or is there any other mistake I made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced same issue as well, I think the interceptors are not initialized correctly, I end up do like below, put the code in the constructor when initializing the api instance

```
_apiInstance = openapi.Openapi(
        basePathOverride: "your url",
        interceptors: [
          InterceptorsWrapper(onRequest: (options, handler) {
            options.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer $token';
            return handler.next(options);
          })
        ]);
```

the onRequest method will be trigger in each request, so in the events that the token changed or updated, it will get the latest token

Comment: I added token into interceptor list after receiving a token. Thanks for answer!

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue, dug deeper into the generated source code, and found a clean solution also based on interceptors, but with less boilerplate.

You need to call `setBearerAuth` as follows:

```dart
openapi.setBearerAuth('bearer', token);
```

This should work out of the box if you do not register any custom `interceptors` when [constructing](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/resources/dart/libraries/dio/api_client.mustache#L23) the `openapi` instance. In this case, by default, a [`BearerAuthInterceptor`](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/resources/dart/libraries/dio/auth/bearer_auth.mustache#L17) instance will be added to the `interceptors` list of the used `Dio` client. This interceptor takes care of patching the request headers:

```dart
options.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ${token}';
```

The [GitHub source code](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/tree/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/resources/dart/libraries/dio) of the generator was helpful as I was looking into this problem.